# OpenCV matrix multiplication with unknown number type

Tags: c++, opencv, multiplication, mat

I'm having some processing i.e. some matrix operations using Mat in OpenCV and the following line gives error:

```
matC = matA*matB;
```

This time, the error is not that difficult to identify since I've already known that the matrix dimensions are correct and their number types are either CV_64FC1 or CV_32FC1.

So, I can fix this error by identifying each matrix's number type (perhaps with some if-else) and replace with a temporary matrix (Mat) that is type compatible

However, in terms of the implementation of OpenCV Mat multiplication, is it a good one? Do we really have to check the operands' number type (and even number of channel e.g. CV_64FC3, CV_64FC2) every time a matrix operation is performed?

is this type of checking barely avoided? since matA or matB are probably returned from a function call such as solvePnP(..., matA, matB,...) and number type of matA, matB are undefined

Thanks,

PS: I've stuck with OpenCV matrix operation several times, problems with number type, number of channels...

Edit 01:

I'm sorry for not being clear in my question! but I'm doing my best to make myself clear

my questions are:

1) should I and how would I do to ensure matC = matA*matB is a error-free operation?

2) in case there should be some checking before the operation, then, should I do that every time such matrix operation is performed? is there a better choice to not replicate such checking?

Edit 02:

here is what I currently do to perform the checking:

```
tmp1 = Vect32Homo(Mat(objPoints.at<Vec3f>(i)));

if (s1To.depth() !=  tmp1.depth())
{
    printf("Different Number Type!");
    s1To.convertTo(s1To, CV_64FC1);
    tmp1.convertTo(tmp1, CV_64FC1);
}   else
{
    printf("Same Number Type!");
}

tmp = s1To*tmp1;  // error prone operation
```

As you may see that this attempt will not work if the two matrices have different number of channel

Comment: Sorry, I'm not intending to be rude, but I've read your question several times and I still don't understand what you're asking. Is it just that you are questioning the design decisions of OpenCV? If so, that's off-topic here and likely to result in the question being closed. Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Try reshaping them to a single channel matrix, operations on matrix aren't well defined for multi-color arrays.
There is a reshape() function that simply changes the header withotu copyign data

Comment: @Beckett: how about number type difference? are you suggesting that I should unify their channel and number type using reshape before doing matrix operations? I'm not sure that is your advice